# Delete branches in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

I've created lots of branches in one of our repositories. Those branches are for testing before it will be pulled to the master. Now I see lots of them on the list and they we will never use it again. How to delete those branches directly to Bitbucket?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

If the branches are only local, you can use **-d** if the branch has been merged, like

```
git branch -d branch-name
```

If the branch contains code you never plan on merging, use **-D** instead.

If the branch is in the upstream repo (on Bitbucket) you can remove the remote reference by

```
git push origin :branch-name
```

Also, if you're on the Bitbucket website, you can remove branches you've pushed by going to the **Feature branches** tab under **Commits** on the site. There you'll find an ellipsis icon. Click that, then choose **Delete branch**. Just be sure you want to drop all the changes there!

[image]

Comment: If I run 'git branch -r', I notice that BB isn't deleting the branch from the server.  It no longer shows up in the GUI, but its shows on the git server.

Comment: There are some branches that BitBucket simply will not allow deleting.

Comment: Looks like not allowing for me: `remote: external-pre-receive-hook declined
remote: fatal: not a tree object
remote: tar: This does not look like a tar archive
remote: tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

Comment: @jerseybean - `git remote prune origin` should help you out. I'm 2 years later but hopefully it will help someone.

Answer (score 62):

For deleting branch from Bitbucket,

1. Go to Overview (Your repository > *branches* in the left sidebar)
2. Click the number of branches (that should show you the list of branches)
3. Click on the branch that you want to delete
4. On top right corner, click the 3 dots (besides Merge button).
5. There is the option of "Delete Branch" if you have rights.

Comment: Where is 'overview'? If you mean Source, I see no 'Delete Branch' option under the ...

Comment: Step 1 should be "go to your repo and click 'branches' in the left sidebar."

Answer (score 28):

In addition to the answer given by @Marcus you can now also delete a remote branch via:

```
git push [remote-name] --delete [branch-name]
```

Answer (score 16):

I could delete most of my branches but one looked like this and I could not delete it:

[image]

Turned out someone had set `Branch permissions` under `Settings` and from there unchecked `Allow deleting this branch`. Hope this can help someone.

[image]

**Update**: Where settings are located from question in comment. Enter the repository that you wan't to edit to get the menu. You might need admin privileges to change this.

[image]

Comment: Where can one find the "Settings"? I have to delete the main branch or all the files in it. How do I do it?

Comment: That's on Bitbucket website

Answer (score 14):

In **Bitbucket** go to branches on the left hand side menu.

1. Select your branch you want to delete.
2. Go to action column, click on three dots (...) and select "delete branch".

Answer (score 9):

In **Bitbucket** go to your project, click branches , click on the three points and click **delete multiple**.

This option for mass delete.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've wrote this small script when the number of branches in my repo exceeded several hundreds. I did not know about the other methods (with CLI) so I decided to automate it with selenium. It simply opens Bitbucket website, goes to Branches, scrolls down the page to the end and clicks on every branch options menu -> clicks Delete button -> clicks Yes. It can be tuned to keep the last N (100 - default) branches and skip branches with specific names (master, develop - default, could be more).
 If this fits for you, you can try that way.

https://github.com/globad/remove-old-branches

All you need is to clone the repository, download the proper version of Chrome-webdriver, input few constants like URL to your repository and run the script.

The code is simple enough to understand. If you have any questions, write comments / create an Issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a pycharm IDE for development and you already have added Git with it. you can directly delete remote branch from pycharm.
**From toolbar VCS-->Git-->Branches-->Select branch-->and Delete**.
It will delete it from remote git server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command, it will purge all branches that have been merged to the `develop` branch.

```
for i in `git branch -r --merged origin/develop| grep origin | grep -v '>' \
   | grep -v master | grep -v develop | sed -E "s|^ *origin/||g"`; \
do \
   git push origin $i --delete; \
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Android Studio**, the options down the right corner of the IDE:

- Change/checkout other local branch
- Delete unwanted local branches (i.e. v0.0.1...)
- **Delete unwanted remote branches** (i.e. origin/v0.0.1...) -- this step will delete branches in BitBucket if the branches are not prevented to be deleted and they are not the **MAIN BRANCH**.

Answer (score 0):

In bitbucket web console., delete branch is disabled when there are active Pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

This one will surely work and is easy to do.

1. Open your repository in stash/bitbucket url of your repo on browser.
2. On the left bottom, if >> arrow is present, click on it.
3. Now scroll down/up, till you find Branches text/link in the left menu and click on it.
4. In dropdown or search box, type your branch name to search till it appears in the list below.
5. The last column in the list with ...(3 dots) and header as Actions, click on the same and click on "Delete branch".

Note: Ensure that you click the dots / delete your own branch that you intend to do.