# Delete multiple branches in a single run

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

I can see the article [Delete branches in Bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150671/delete-branches-in-bitbucket) but this is just deleting single branch at a time.
I want to delete multiple branches in a single run, does this possible by command line or manually?

Comment: Just pass multiple branch names:  `git branch -d foo bar baz`

Answer (score 8):

**Step 1, local branches**

Like Flimzy suggested, `branch -d` accepts a series of refs.

Also, if needed, maybe consider having a first command to generate the branch list, and pass the result to the branch command. For example if you decided to delete merged branches

```
git branch -d `git branch --merged`
```

or, other hypothetical situation, if you want to get rid of all branches having some bad commit (introduced a bug)

```
git branch -d `git branch --contains <bad-commit>`
```

In this second example, git might complain that some branches are not fully merged, i.e. have commits that are present only on them, not reachable from any other branches. It's a safeguard to avoid accidentally losing work, right in the git principles.

To override this mechanism in cases where you **do** know that these branches are not fully merged but you still want to delete them, the alternative is to use the `-D` flag instead of `-d`, but beware if you use this in conjonction with a list like we saw above, or be **sure** to output and check the list *before* feeding it to the deletion command.

---

**Step 2, remote branches**

And to answer Vlad's useful comment, yes this operation only affects the local repo, so to reflect it on remote (I'll here assume `origin` but do adapt it to your case), you'd have to

```
git push -d origin <branchList>
```

---

**Step 3, remote-tracking branches**

Finally, as your local repo still at this point retains the obsolete remote-tracking branches corresponding to the remote branches we just deleted, finish with a

```
git remote prune origin
# or
git fetch --prune
```

Comment: Can you update this to include how to ensure these deletions are reflected in the remote and not just locally?

Comment: @Vlad274 You're right, this was a useful thing to add. Edited.

Comment: how to delete multiple remote branches?

Comment: @Yohanim In my answer's step 2, `<branchList>` is the placeholder for your list of branches. What's unclear?

Comment: @RomainValeri Oops I don't notice it. thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use, Linux/Unix grep command ability.

`grep "*keyword*"` will list similar name.

Merge grep command with `git branch`.

To delete branch we use `git branch -d branch_name`

So, final command looks like:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with the VS 2019 git experience.
The most usefull post I found was:
[How to delete multiple local Git branches from Sourcetree?](https://abhimuralidharan.medium.com/how-to-delete-multiple-local-git-branches-from-sourcetree-e33bd97eac46)

Of course, this means you have to install sourcetree, but hey: it beats spending an hour repeatedly selecting, deleting and conforming the delete of a branch...